# I dont understand this error: dataobj is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

js code

```
  var dataObj = {};
  var shipDataObj = [];
  function shipData(shipDataObj){

      for(i=0;i<shipDataObj.length;i++){
          dataObj.push({
          addressLine1 : shipDataObj[i].addressLine1, 
          addressLine2 : shipDataObj[i].addressLine2,
          city : shipDataObj[i].city,
          state : shipDataObj[i].state,
          country : shipDataObj[i].country,
          zip : shipDataObj[i].zipCode,
          contactNum : shipDataObj[i].contactNumber
          });
   }
  }


   appServices.getAddress(userData.customerId).then(function (data){

                    if (data){  
                          console.log(data);
                          $scope.shipDataObj = data;
                          shipData(data);
                        console.log(dataObj);
                    }
                    });
```

I need only 7 properties from data.I copied data object in shipDataObj and called a function named shipData. shipData will push the properties in shipDataObj. shipDataObj may have two indexes like 0 and 1 each of them have those 7 properties.these 7 properties I have to push in dataObj so that I can display only these properties.

I dont understand why this error is coming dataObj is not a function.

Comment: sure it doesn't say `dataObj.push` is not a function?

Comment: @charlietfl yes it does

Comment: ok...so the clue there is ... all arrays should have `push` available, so if it's not available then there is problem of `dataObj` not being an array. Thus you get to point's answer. Important to read error closely

Comment: @Pallavi Look at the first line: `var dataObj = {};`

Comment: yeah thanks guys I appreciate your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of your `dataObj` variable is an object reference, and objects don't have a `.push()` method. If you really want it to be an array, its initialization should look like

```
var dataObj = [];
```